# Retain NULL in MAX() ORDER BY

Tags: sql, oracle10g, aggregate-functions

I have the following query with the resultant output.

```
select seq_no, timestamp, 
max(timestamp) over (partition by seq_no) as max
from temp
```

```
SEQ_NO  TIMESTAMP       MAX
1       6/27/2013 15:42 6/27/2013 15:43
1       6/27/2013 15:43 6/27/2013 15:43
1       6/27/2013 15:43 6/27/2013 15:43
1       6/27/2013 15:43 6/27/2013 15:43
2                       6/27/2013 15:44
2       6/27/2013 15:44 6/27/2013 15:44
```

In the case of the ***highlighted*** value you can see that the calculated MAX() does not retain the NULL value.  I believe I've read that by default the MAX() function ignores NULLs, so this makes sense... but... I would like to retain the NULL for the row, meaning that the entries for SEQ_NO=2 would look like the following.

```
SEQ_NO  TIMESTAMP       MAX
2                       
2       6/27/2013 15:44 6/27/2013 15:44
```

I've tried playing with the KEEP() function but am not clear I'm on the right path.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... you want the max timestamp for each seq_no _except_ on rows that have `NULL` timestamps? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to set the max column value when the original value is null.  The issue is that I'm also looking to use this result in another calculation so I'm hoping to simplify the statement.

Comment: Then Gordon's answer below will work well, just wanted to make sure I understood your intention properly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `case` statement:

```
select seq_no, timestamp, 
       (case when timestamp is not null
             then max(timestamp) over (partition by seq_no)
        end) as maxtimestamp
from temp
```

Comment: This works fine and I will accept as answer but I was hoping for something that could also be included in another analytic function.  Thanks!